# Sensu mailer ignores check occurrences settings

Tags: sensu

Hi the sensu mailer handler started recently to send alerts after only 1 occurrence. no matter how occurrences i put in the check config file.

do you know how can i address this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details. Did you change anything when the problem started to occur? What is your current configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that one of the gem dependencies were updated.

the solution:
we needed to downgrade the sensu-plugin to 1.4.4

in later versions of sensu-plugin the default filter that responsible to check the event occurrence vs the check configuration is obsolete.

https://sensuapp.org/blog/2016/07/07/sensu-plugin-filter-deprecation.html